# Find the user role of the currently logged in user

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to know the current logged in Users User Role.

I have 2 roles in my application.

USER_ROLE and ADMIN_ROLE

How can i know if the current logged in user belongs to one of the above roles.

I tried the following code and i get an error:

```
org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService authenticateService = new org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService()
def isAdmin = authenticateService.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')

if(isAdmin) {
   println 'I am Admin'
}
```

The error is :

```
Groovy:unable to resolve class 

org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService

- Groovy:unable to resolve class
```

I am using grails 2.2.4

SPring security ----> compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information via static methods on the [SpringSecurityUtils](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityUtils) class

```
if(SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")) ....
```

Comment: THis is what i get `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SpringSecurityUtils`

Comment: @Ilep of course you need to add the relevant `import` - as it says on the documentation page I've linked to, the full class name is `grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where you got that from, but you need:

```
boolean isAdmin = grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

Comment: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: SpringSecurityUtils` the error i get